# Poltergeist: phantomjs_logger option ignored

Tags: rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

In this setup:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
    phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--load-images=no'], debug: false, timeout: 500, screen_size: [1600, 1200], js_errors: false,.
    logger: File.open( Rails.root.join("./log/test.poltergeist.log").to_s, "a" ),
    phantomjs_logger: File.open( Rails.root.join("./log/test.phantomjs_console.log").to_s, "a" )
  })
end
```

Phantomjs ignores the phantomjs_logger option and dumps everything the application outputs to the console to STDOUT, so I get shown a load of garbage when running my specs.

I have tried with no luck setting phantomjs_logger to Logger.new(...), to File.open("/dev/null",...), to nil, false and pretty much everything you can think of, it just doesn't do anything.

Ideally I'd want errors to fail the test and other .info .log whatever messages just piped to the log file. But I can live with having it all sent to the log file as well.

Later edit: seems this is happening with chrome headless as well. It just dumps console.log into stdout :(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `phantomjs_logger` only affects info being sent to STDOUT of the phantomjs process - not things that would be sent to STDERR - are you sure the info you're seeing is being sent to STDOUT of the phantomjs process?

Comment: I got it to work as shown below after seeing in the source it logs to $stdout. Not sure why that was...happy I’m no longer stuck at this. Had to deal with a lot of frustration over capybara tests the last couple days, lots of things that just don’t work. Or maybe it’s not capybara itself but the drivers like phantomjs chrome webkit and so on.

Comment: If you are testing modern apps you really don't want to be using Poltergeist anymore - It's JS/CSS support is basically equal to a 7 year old Safari (limitation of the abandoned PhantomJS project)-- You're going to be much happier using headless chrome or firefox (with the added benefit you can always turn off headless if you ever need to see whats actually happening on the page).

Comment: Thanks. I have chrome set up as well, I managed to test some parts of a SPA. It crashes a lot when trying to test rails views. Will keep playing with it.

Comment: If it's Chrome crashing that's very strange -- if your app is crashing then most likely your controller/view code.  Either way create a new question with an example of what you're seeing and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: It was chrome, actually I just gave it a 2nd look and did an update, it's not crashing anymore. Now I can get rid of poltergeist and do my thing with chrome. Thank you so much Thomas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours wasted on this I managed to get it to work by opening the log into $stdout. Not sure why it couldn't work as per docs but oh well.

```
$stdout = File.open( Rails.root.join("./log/test.phantomjs_console.log").to_s )

require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
    phantomjs: "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs", # '>> ./log/test.phantomjs_console.log 2>&1'
    phantomjs_options: [ '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--load-images=no', '--debug=false' ], debug: false, timeout: 500, window_size: [1600, 1200], js_errors: false,.
    logger: File.open( Rails.root.join("./log/test.poltergeist.log").to_s, "a" ),
    phantomjs_logger: $stdout
  })
end
```

Later edit: managed to set up chrome in the meanwhile. Poltergeist is outdated. If you run into this q/a and you're trying to get poltergeist to work, stop and switch to chrome.